# How to add the leave to all employee in the list in java and mysql

Tags: java

I am creating a Simple Payroll System for my Final Year Project.i ran in to problem with add the leave to employee. if i add the leave it will added to all the employee belong to the company.but i couldn't do the task what i tried so i written below of code.
For the example 
 if i selected the leave casual leave as 20 days . it added all employee no in the list.

**Employee Table**

[image]

**Leave Table**

[image]

[image]

**Code which i tried so**

```
    String cas = txtcas.getValue().toString();
     String anu = txtanu.getValue().toString();
     String med = txtmed.getValue().toString();
     String year = txtyear.getText();

    try {
        int c;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/spay","root","");
       PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement("select empno from employee");
        ResultSet rs = pst1.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<String> empnos = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
     empnos.add(rs.getString(1));

        pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into leaves(empno,casual,annual,address,medical,year)values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1,) ); // employee no how to give here
        pst.setString(2, cas);
        pst.setString(3, anu);
         pst.setString(4, med);
        pst.setString(5, year);         
        pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Leave Insertedddddd");
         }
```

Database output comes to look like this

[image]

Comment: You should also get the  `employee no` from the GUI along with the other parameters `cas, anu, med, year`. For that the Client GUI has to know who is going to apply the leave. I am not sure how your app flow is, but assuming let say John( the employee)  applies a leave the GUI might already have the detail about the employee so you could pass that to backend.

Comment: no sir i just need  i shown the leave form above just select the leaves causal and annual,medial thats leaves are added all the employees thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// This is the code to get the data from table for a particular column.

```
String empNoValue; 
while (rs.next()) {
 empNoValue = rs.getString("empno"); // empno is the column name
}
```

Before that,

1 you need to add the some WHERE Condition for taking the specific employee in query pst1.

Otherwise,

1 You need to set the `session` value or the `hidden` value from the before page for that employee.

1.1 After that you got the specific employee (from that `hidden` or `session` value) whose data add to the table.

```
String employeeValue = hidden or session value // from privious page
```

then add the employeeValue to the insert query like below

```
pst.setString(1, employeeValue); // employeeValue is the your specific empno get from privious page
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that pst1 is declared somewhere earlier in the code, and in

> ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

you are actually calling pst1 and not pst

For the required output you need to iterate over the result set, something like this

```
PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement("select empno from employee");
ResultSet rs = pst1.executeQuery();
List<String> empnos = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
      empnos.add(rs.getString(1));
   }
```

and then use the arraylist for your usecase

Do read about getting the result set values on internet as well, it will help you for your future questions

Comment: List<String> empnos = new ArrayList<>(); this getting Error sir Error shown list does not take parameters

Comment: Modify the code above sir how to pass empno  pst.setString(1,) ); sir

Comment: List<String> empnos = new ArrayList<String>(); You can run a loop for the insert query or use a batch insert for inserting the values fetched from the result set.

Comment: Hi sir i have modified the above code what i got from the database table. not added the empno properly i shown the database table as well